# AvroStorage - output file name definition

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I use AvroStorage to store result set from the pig. Is there a way how can I store data into one specified avro file...e.g  OutputFileGen1? Pig is storing data into the directory named OutpuFileGen1 with structure as listed below:

```
 ls -al  OutputFileGen1/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2016-01-18 14:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 2016-01-19 10:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4083 2016-01-18 14:35 part-m-00000.avro
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   40 2016-01-18 14:35 .part-m-00000.avro.crc
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 2016-01-18 14:35 _SUCCESS
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    8 2016-01-18 14:35 ._SUCCESS.crc
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of part in the pig output directory depends on how many parallel task your job does. Here you have only have one file : part-m-00000.

http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html#Use+the+Parallel+Features

But maybe you want a single file in purpose, so if you want to get this file I suggest to use the `hadoop fs -getmerge <src dir> <target dir>`command, to get the file in the local file system in order to use the data it contains.

Comment: can i execute -getmerge <src dir> <target dir> , so that target directory, based on the requirements, will be hdfs or local FS?

Comment: I dont think you can merge multiple files into one on local non HDFS FS system ;-(